# Cómo extraer los datos especifico de una pagina web en vb.net 2022 indicando su id?

Tags: vb.net

tengo la siguiente url: http://www.cne.gob.ve/web/index.php; solicito ayuda como puedo extraer los datos personales al indicar su id ejemplo: v-12345678, E-12345678, mostrar en un textbox2 los datos que coincidan con lo ingresado en un textbox1[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Comment: El enlace que provees no es accesible (al menos no desde España). Por otro lado, ¿Qué dice la legislación de Venezuela sobre el uso de la información personal que aparece en dicho portal? Has pedido consentimiento al sr. JONATHAN para publicar su número de identificación personal en [es.so]? Nunca publiques información personal en sitios públicos sin la aprobación explícita del propietario. Saludos

Comment: gracias por responder, tome un numero aleatorio para mostrar el ejemplo e ilustrar el requerimiento. tratare de modificar la imagen,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Paso 1: Obtener la URL real**

Abres la página, presionas F12 y vas a la pestaña "Red". Luego realizas la búsqueda y obtienes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como observarás en la URL van como querystring los datos necesario para la consulta, es decir el tipo de documento según nacionalidad (V o E) y la cedula. Además sabemos que se debe utilizar el method GET

**Paso 2: Crear una función que retorne como string esta página**

```
 Function GetData(Nacionalidad As Char, cedula As String)
        Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
        Dim url As String = $"http://www.cne.gob.ve/web/registro_electoral/ce.php?nacionalidad={Nacionalidad}&cedula={cedula}"
        Return client.GetStringAsync(url).Result
 End Function
```

**Paso 3: Obtener los datos dentro de la tabla**

La función anterior retorna un string en formato HTML, en especifico una tabla. Ahora debemos obtener lo que está dentro de cada celda `<td>esto_es_lo_que_queremos</rd>`, para esto usaremos expresiones regulares

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim tabla = GetData("V", "14428549")
    Dim resultados = Regex.Matches(tabla, "<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td>")

    For Each r As Match In resultados
        Dim contenido As String = r.Groups(1).Value
        Console.WriteLine(contenido)
    Next
End Sub
```

El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Paso 4: Obtener los datos importantes y limpiar**

De lo anterior, sabemos que queremos las líneas: 6,8,10,11,13,15,17. Y que hay que limpiar la líneas 8,15 y 17 ya que contienen aun mas etiquetas HTML

Entonces el código completo quedaría algo así:

```
Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim tabla = GetData("V", "14428549")
        Dim resultados = Regex.Matches(tabla, "<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td>")


        Dim cedulda = resultados(6).Groups(1).Value
        Dim nombre = resultados(8).Groups(1).Value.Replace("<b>", "").Replace("</b>", "")
        Dim estado = resultados(10).Groups(1).Value
        Dim municipio = resultados(11).Groups(1).Value
        Dim parroquia = resultados(13).Groups(1).Value
        Dim centro = resultados(15).Groups(1).Value.Replace("<font color=""#0000FF"">", "").Replace("</font>", "")
        Dim direccion = resultados(17).Groups(1).Value.Replace("<font color=""#0000FF"">", "").Replace("</font>", "")

        Console.WriteLine("Cedula : " & cedulda)
        Console.WriteLine("Nombre : " & nombre)
        Console.WriteLine("Estado : " & estado)
        Console.WriteLine("Municipio : " & municipio)
        Console.WriteLine("Parroquia : " & parroquia)
        Console.WriteLine("Centro : " & centro)
        Console.WriteLine("Dirección : " & direccion)
    End Sub

    Function GetData(Nacionalidad As Char, cedula As String)
        Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
        Dim url As String = $"http://www.cne.gob.ve/web/registro_electoral/ce.php?nacionalidad={Nacionalidad}&cedula={cedula}"
        Return client.GetStringAsync(url).Result
    End Function
End Module
```

Cuyo resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @NelsonD́Soto Eso escapa de mis conocimientos, supongo que con reconocimiento de imágenes se podría hacer algo, como por ejemplo con OpenCV. Además hay ciertos aspectos éticos que ni yo ni este sitio quieren transgredir, ya que si el sistema cuenta con captcha es justamente para evitar que otros sistemas realicen consultas automatizadas.